# How to restrict S3 file upload to a bucket by certain file type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried creating a bucket policy as below to allow file upload only by jpeg and png and restrict the rest of the types.

```
{
"Id": "Policy1464968545158",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
 {
  "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
  "Action": [
    "s3:PutObject"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*.jpg",
  "Principal": "*"
 },
 {
  "Sid": "Stmt1464968543787",
  "Action": [
    "s3:PutObject"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*.png",
  "Principal": "*"
 }
]
}
```

But this does not work as it allows file upload of other file types (Eg. pdf etc.,). Kindly assist towards getting my use case solved. Thanks!

Comment: FIlename extensions are not a guarantee of filetype. For example, I could rename a PDF to have a `.jpg` extension and it could upload. You might want to consider [Uploading objects using presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to only allow uploads when your application permits, including restrictions on path and filename (but not specifically "file type").

Comment: This policy doesn't restrict anything. An IAM principal with permission to write to the bucket can upload whatever content they want. What it does do, however, is allow anyone on the internet, with or without credentials, to overwrite jpg/png files in your bucket, which I doubt is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of `Deny` with [NotResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notresource.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*.jpg",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*.png"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Your policy only checks for extension of files, not whether the actual file upload is jpeg or png, and does not account for their variations, such as JPG, PNG, JPEG, and more. Extensions can be inaccurate.

As a side note, its is a bad practice, to allow anonymous uploads to your bucket. If you have other possibilities than this, it would be worth considering them first.